# Get Users Who has Birthday Today in their TimeZone

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, timezone

We have users from multiple timezone and our command runs and see if we have a user whose birthday is today in their timezone.

**DB Structure**

```
id => bigInt
name => string
dob => datetime
timezone => string
```

dob = Date Of Birth
timezone = ex: America/New_York

**We get all users whose birthday was yesterday, today and tomorrow on UTC time to cover all timezones** and get limited users instead of all users

```
    $users = User::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') = '" . now()->format('m-d') . "'")
        ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') = '" . now()->subDay(1)->format('m-d') . "'")
        ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') = '" . now()->addDay(1)->format('m-d') . "'")
        ->selectRaw('*')
        ->whereNotNull('timezone')->get();
```

Then we loop through these users and see if a user's birthday is today in their timezone at a specific time like 9:00AM then we send them greetings.

```
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->isMorningForUserOnBirthday()) {
            $user->notify(new BirthdayNotification($user));
        }
    }
```

Function **isMorningForUserOnBirthday()**

```
public function isMorningForUserOnBirthday()
{
    // its birthday date and for that user its time at 9:00AM
    if ((now($this->timezone)->day == $this->dob->day) && now($this->timezone)->hour == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**What We are Looking Far:** we are getting results and all is working fine, next phase after working fine is making it awesome,

we want to refactor Eloquent Query and instead of using that function **isMorningForUserOnBirthday()** we want use MySql native things that could use users 'timezone' column and get us users whose birthday is today.

Comment: how do you store the `timezone`, what kind of values are there like timezone offset `+6:00` or timezone name `Africa/Accra`

Comment: thank you @Kalhan.Toress, very valid question and i'll update question as well. we store timezone name like America/New_York

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure that we take into considerations that some timezones are not just a difference of hours ([there are some 30/45 mins difference](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html)) we will need to run the scheduled command every 15 mins.

The helper function that you can add to your `Users` model would look like this

```
public function getUsersMatchingTodayHourInTheirTimezone($column_name, $time)
    {
        return $this->selectRaw("*, DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(DATE($column_name), ' $time:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %T'), timezone, '+00:00'), '%m-%d %H:%i') as column_at_utc")
            ->having('column_at_utc', '=', now()->format('m-d H:i'))
            ->whereNotNull('timezone')
            ->get();
    }
```

Assuming that dob is `1989-07-28 00:00:00` or `1989-07-28` format.

You can change the `$column_name` (in this example we use `dob`) column to be whatever you want and you can also change the `$time` (In this example we wanted 9am for the user `09`) to be whatever hour you want.

Assuming that you are running his on a system when the system and application time is set to UTC.

Calling this every 15 mins will make sure that you only get the users returned when it is the required time for them.

Answer (score 2):

The logic in my head is that

Lets say i want to get all the users who are celebrating their birthdays on a given UTC date_time

EX: given date is: `06-04 (UTC) (which is in month-date format)`

and all the dob are saved in the db with respective timezone, so now based on dob and their timezone we can calculate the UTC date for each dob

```
CONVERT_TZ(dob, timezone, "+00:00")
//CONVERT_TZ (dt, from_tz, to_tz)
```

This says that `dob` is in this `timezone` (because we save their dob in their timezone) and then we say [convert](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-convert_tz-function.php) it to UTC by passing `+00:00`

now we can use current UTC date to filter out the results

```
SELECT
    name,
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(dob, timezone, "+00:00"), "%m-%d") as dob_utc
    FROM users HAVING dob = "07-01";
```

We need `DATE_FORMAT` because when checking `dob`, the `year` is not important.

When we put that in to laravel

```
$utc = now()->format('m-d')

$users = User::selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(dob, timezone, '+00:00'), '%m-%d') as dob_utc")
    ->having("dob_utc", "=", $utc)
    ->whereNotNull('timezone')
    ->get();
```

Not tested

Comment: this is great but query doesn't work with with timezone string like `America/New_York` but it work with '-05:00' as my friend @jamesmills mention

"To do this, you’ll need to set up the time zone tables first. The MySQL installation procedure creates the time zone tables, but it doesn’t load them. Therefore, you’ll need to populate these tables first.
If you try to use a named time zone with this function without first populating the time zone tables, you’ll get a null value."

Comment: This is a fantastic answer with some great depth of explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you cant send right on 9am by running the function in each hour, so lets say my timezone is `+05:30` then you have to run the function on each half and hour isnt it?

Comment: Yer, this is a good point. I've sort of assumed that hourly and catching everything within that hour will work. The solution I've posted doesn't match the question exactly but it should work for what we needed. Thank you for your help.